Do there exist strictly contracting eikonal functions on $\mathbb R^n$?
A function $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is said to be a strict contraction if
$$|f(x) - f(y)| < |x - y|$$
for all $x \neq y$.
A function $f$ is said to be eikonal if it is differentiable everywhere, and $|\nabla f| = 1$ almost everywhere.
Question: Let $n \geq 2$.  Do there exist eikonal strict contractions on $\mathbb R^n$?

For each $\delta > 0$, do you have any estimates on the "size" on the set ${(x, y): |f(y) - f(x)| \leq (1 - \delta) |x - y|}$ assuming that $f$ is eikonal? It seems to me that such a set must be "small", in particular it feels like it should be first-category.

@ChristianRemling How??? (for "smooth if desired"). In the smooth case you can travel along the gradient field making the increment of $f$ at least the traveled distance on a curve and, thereby, at least the Euclidean distance between its endpoints, contradicting strong contractivity.

@AidanBackus While I’m not sure about the “smooth if desired” part, it is the differentiable everywhere condition that would make such a set small if anything. Otherwise, taking the function to be $\text{dist}(\cdot, x)$ for some point $x$, we get a lot of points satisfying the $(1-\delta)$ contractivity.

@fedja: This is exactly how I wanted to prove the strict contraction property, except that I move along a straight line. So it would suffice to produce a curl free unit vector field that is not constant on any line segment. Apparently I messed up the PDE part.
